# On using "outperform"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Can the word `outperform` replaces `achieve faster performance`.

> X methods can achieve faster performance than Y.

Become

> X methods can outperform Y.

Does sentence 2 gives the same meaning as sentence 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does so only if the sole measure of performance is speed of performance. X methods might outperform Y by being, for example, more reliable, softer on the skin, more beautiful ..

short point: you cannot use 'outperform' unless you can state how performance is assessed.

Comment: So if I say: X methods can outperform Y in performance?

Comment: That is grammatical, but so uninformative that any reader would think that you are having some kind of joke at their expense. For the word 'outperform' to have any meaning then you have to define what you mean by performance and how to tell if A's performance is superior to B's. That does not necessarily mean that the performance has to be quantifiable, but it does mean that it must be capable of being ordered. You have to be able to define what 'better performance' means.